# Click Event not working in VUE JS application?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, onclick, vue-component

I just installed the app, tried to follow the documentation, I tried to display a simple text in the button, after that wanted to add a simple event

Added my method click, and my function in methods object, but the click isn't working, I see no error in the console, it seems like the click is just there as an html attribute when I checked the elements in the inspector

I am working with VUE JS 2

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button v:on-click="lookAtAlert()">{{btnText}}</button>
    <!-- <NavigationBar></NavigationBar>
    <ContainerApp></ContainerApp> -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
/*
import NavigationBar from './components/NavigationBar/index.vue'
import ContainerApp from './components/ContainerApp/index.vue'
*/
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data: function(){ 
    return {
      btnText: "CLICK"
    }
  },
  methods: {
    lookAtAlert: function() {
      console.log("HELLO ?")
    }
  },
  components: {
    /*
    NavigationBar,
    ContainerApp
    */
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

What else did I try ?

```
<button v:on-click="lookAtAlert">{{btnText}}</button>
```

ALSO this :

```
<button v:on-click.native="lookAtAlert()">{{btnText}}</button>
```

And this :

```
<button v:on-click.native="lookAtAlert">{{btnText}}</button>
```

ALSO this :

```
<button @click="lookAtAlert()">{{btnText}}</button>
```

And this :

```
<button @click="lookAtAlert">{{btnText}}</button>
```

Nothing seems to work, any help on this would be much appreciated.

my package.json because it may be something related to some installations :

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `v-on:some-event` or `@some-event` and don't call method with `()`, You can find more here -> [`vue2`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html?redirect=true):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() { 
    return {
      btnText: "CLICK"
    }
  },
  methods: {
    lookAtAlert() {
      console.log("HELLO ?")
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="lookAtAlert">{{ btnText }}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried calling the method with () and without, nothing seems to work